# Using a button to show certain elements

Tags: jquery, parameters, show

### CODE HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/B7Y43/

Hello fello programmers,

I have the following situation:

**My PHP-script generates multiple DIV's, containing:**

- A question (with a class that is either mainQuestion or subQuestionOf[questionID])
- A button
- A paragraph containing the answer

**I am trying to achieve the following:**

When the user clicks the button next to the question, the answer AND the subquestions should fadeIn. I have already managed to fadeIn the answer when the user clicks the button, using `$(this).next('p').fadeIn("fast");`
 but since the subQuestions are rarely the next div, I think I need the use parameters.

So in pseudo-code:

```
<question id="1" subquestionOf=""><button>
<answer>
<question id="2" subquestionOf="1"><button>
<answer>
<question id="3" subquestionOf="1"><button>
<answer>

if user clicks button {
show answer;
show questions where subquestionof=parent.id;
}
```

I have no idea how to use parameters, I tried getting the ID of the button's parent div with no luck:

```
$(function getID(event){
            var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
            alert(id);
    });
```

Alert shows: "Undefined"

Comment: Why define a function inside of a document-onload handler? And do nothing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried (modifying your code in jsFiddle):

```
$("input.showAnswerButton").click(function() {
        $(this).next('p').fadeIn("fast"); //answer
        //subquestions
        $('.subQuestionOf'+$(this).parent().attr("id")).fadeIn("fast");
    });
```

and it's working...

Comment: That did it, easier than I thought, thanks a lot manji :-)
Is there anyway I can name the ID's of parent DIV's, something other then [ID], and still maintain functionality of the script?

Comment: with your current html and this solution, id must contain an index. You can change it but keep the index retrievable from it. You can also store this index in the 'name' attribute and use `attr('name')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) from the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) to get the id of the clicked button.

Are you debugging using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to check the values of `$(this)` and the result of `.parent()`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I replaced $(this) with $(event.target) (is this what you meant?).
But I still get undefined as my browser output.
I dont use Firebug, I will look into it, thanks a lot. I hope you didn't get tens of email from stackoverflow; I had trouble writing this comment without accidentaly submitting it.

Comment: Hi Michiel, I only got the one notification :) The code `$(event.target)` is right (as you're putting that DOM element into a wrapped jQuery set). You can go to the Script tab of Firebug, and put a break point on the line that contains that call (by selecting the script in the dropdown that contains all of them, then by clicking to the left of the line number for that line), in the watch tab on the right hand side, you can add a new watch expression of `$(event.object)` and you should be able to inspect it.